# Call controller from twig and reload page symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, multilingual

I have this controller

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $localeLang = $request->getLocale();
    $lang = $request->request->get('lang');

    if (isset($lang)){
        $newLang = $lang;
    }else{
        $newLang = $localeLang;
    }

    $this->get('session')->set("_locale", $newLang);

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        'base_dir' => realpath($this-
>getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    ]);
}
}
```

In my twig I have buttons to change the language like this:

```
{% block javascripts %}
                    <button id='button1' class="ajax">Español</button>
                    <script>
                        $("button1").click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: {{ 'default' }},
                                data: {
                                    lang: 'es'
                                }
                            });
                        });

                    </script>
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

In my `routing.yml`

```
default:
  path:     /
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index }
```

I have files .xlf with translations `messages.es.xlf`, `messages.en.xlf`.

This is my `config.yml`

```
framework:
  translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
  default_locale: en
```

How can call the `DefaultController.php` from button in twig and pass parameter `lang` to change language and reload the page.

Comment: why don't you just use a link instead of ajax ?

Comment: I'd have to change the route in my controller to `/{lang}` , no?

Comment: or with a query param

Comment: with route `/` I know hoy can I read data in controller but I don't know how create the query in twig when I click button.